# Add Model Run Date into Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an Oracle SQL Query to source some data of our Data Lake into our Business Intelligence Tool.
Now I would like to add the model run date (date-time) /system date to get for every refresh the latest date. But how?
Would you add a column with the date in every row?
Or just one value/ row for the whole column? This would also work for me.

If so, how?
The current sql query is like

```
"SELECT * FROM DBA.MasterData WHERE Article LIKE '%IKL%'
```

Comment: You mean like `CURRENT_DATE` ? As in  `Select col1, col2, ..., colN, CURRENT_DATE FROM DBA.MasterData`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a column with the current date to the query

```
SELECT md.*, sysdate run_date 
  FROM DBA.MasterData md 
 WHERE md.Article LIKE '%IKL%'
```

Most BI tools will have the ability to run multiple queries to populate a single page of your dashboard so you could get a single `run_date` rather than adding a bunch of duplicative data to your query

```
SELECT sysdate run_date
  FROM dual
```

But most BI tools will have a simpler, tool-specific way to add the date the query was executed to the page since that's a pretty common request.

Are you sure that you want to use the current system date?  I personally always find it more useful to use a date populated by your ETL process so that users know what time frame the data actually represents.  When there are problems with an overnight load or some component that a dashboard relies on that is usually close to real-time is lagging by a few hours, that's a lot more useful than something that just blindly populates today's date.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Since every table in our BI tool has it specific refresh horizon, I would like to get for every table a model run date :)